# How to convert .obj file to .stl so I can slice to G-code?

Tags: slicing

I am a beginning maker using an Ender 3. Someone sent me a [.obj file](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2024992) from Thingiverse to print for them. I use an online slicer called [IceSL](https://icesl.loria.fr/slicecrafter/) as a slicer.
As experts on here know, I cannot use my slicer to slice .obj to G-code. How do I convert this .obj file to a .stl file so I can slice and then print it?

Comment: Both Cura and PrusaSlicer can open/import .obj files.

Answer (score 2):

One can import an OBJ file into free program Meshmixer, then export it to STL format. There are other programs that are free and paid (such as Fusion 360) that will perform similar tasks.

As noted by user agarza, Prusa Slicer will import an OBJ and will also export to STL format. PrusaSlicer is also free.